# webpack - generate a script that loads manifest, vendor and bundle

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack to generate manifest, vendor and bundle with their respective hash.
I need to build like an init script that actually imports manifest, vendor and bundle into the page ... i tried using System.import with very little success

Any suggestions on this?

thanks